# Which is correct, "summiting" or "summitting"?

Tags: orthography, gerunds, present-participles, doubled-consonants

This form of the word is not very common but does see some use as the present participle/gerund of "to summit" as in "Upon summit(t)ing the mountain we took photos but had to begin our descent immediately to make it down before dark".

Wiktionary only includes "[summiting](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/summiting)" but of course its publicly editable so no guarantees it's right.

Google suggests "summiting" as a correction when you search for "summitting" but there's not really many Google hits for either to be truly conclusive.

Google Ngram Viewer shows "summiting" in the lead recently...

[image: all time]

... but "summitting" has the highest peak in the graph around about 1910 and was also in the lead from 1974 to 1980...

[image: 1974-1980]

So I'm interested in whether any of the style guides, usage guides, or trusted English dictionaries such as OED or Websters Third have anything to say.

Comment: This question is a bit odd in that it doesn't look in the general references but instead researches actual usage, then asks for gen-ref follow-up.

Comment: @Mr.ShinyandNew安宇 True, but having searched for style guide references on this topic I've found zilch.

Comment: Looking at the data for 1973-1982 in Google books search shows 17 results for "summitting", 7 of which are typos for "submitting", and a few more of which seem to be OCR errors; and 15 for "summiting", some of which also are OCR errors. The usages near 1910 all seem to be typos for "submitting". Google Ngrams rounds down very low rates of data to zero, so I suspect there were "submitting" typos in all years, but there just happened to be enough of a bunch circa 1910 to make a blip on the graph.

Comment: @PeterShor: Aha you may have it. I was thinking about spelling analogies with submitting and also noticed some typos but I didn't thoroughly go through them.

Comment: @Mr.ShinyandNew安宇: Is that a criticism or a point of interest? I've just noticed there is a vote to close but not a clear criticism to accompany it.

Comment: @hippietrail: It wasn't my vote to close, but I am a bit on the fence about a question that explicitly asks for dictionary lookup.

Comment: @Mr.ShinyandNew安宇: In fact I'm asking for any verification. Dict lookup was just an example but not my first choice since most dictionaries don't include inflected forms like participles and gerunds. Besides just because one dictionary doesn't list one of the forms doesn't mean it's not a correct form. It could mean the dictionary isn't complete or doesn't cover both UK and US variants, etc. I do actually own both an OED and a W3 but I'm travelling right now and don't have access to them. I do have access to the web but unexpected findings made me decide asking here would be a good idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Random house list it as [summiting](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/summiting?r=66)

> **verb** (used without object)
>   7.
>   to take part in a summit meeting.
>   8.
>   to reach a summit: summited after a 14-hour climb.
>   **verb** (used with object)
>   9.
>   to reach the summit of.

EDIT:
Tip: Use onelook.com to check multiple dictionaries.

Comment: "Summiting" looks wrong to me, just as "worshiped" does.There may be a [US/UK difference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_and_British_English_spelling_differences#Doubled_consonants) here.

Comment: @ColinFine, it looked a bit wrong to me too, but doesn't the breakdown to syllables and pronunciation make a difference here: *sum·mit·ed, sum·mit·ing, sum·mits* vs *sub·mit·ted, sub·mit·ting, sub·mits*

Comment: "Summited" shouldn't double its 't' because it's accented on the first syllable, just like "limited" and "vomited". (And now you have me worrying about "permitted", which I would accent on the first syllable when it means "issued a permit".) For some reason, "worshipped" is an exception to this rule.

Comment: @Unreason: I think "submitted" is irrelevant, except insofar as many apparent examples are typles.

Comment: @PeterShor: I think you're right. I have no trouble with "limited" and "vomited", "edited", "audited", but "summited" looks wrong.

Comment: @Colin: I suspect "summited" may look wrong to you because it's so close in spelling to "submitted". Similarly, I suspect "worshipped" may be spelled the way it is because it ends with "shipped".

Comment: I'd be entirely happy with an answer showing a real UK/US usage difference if anyone can find one.

Comment: (Necromancy, apologies) @PeterShor Perhaps "worshipped" as an exception has something to do with the fact that "worshiping" just looks _wrong_, unlike "limiting" or "vomiting". So once we get to "worshipping", then "worshipped" just makes sense for consistency. Then again, that just raises another question: What is it about "worshiping" that makes it so eye-searingly Wrong™? (Also, random data point: Modern-day 2018 Google Chrome does indeed flag both "worshipped" and "worshipping", and wants to correct them to "worshiped" and "worshiping". Ew!)

Answer (score 1):

See *benefited*. *Summited* works by the same principle.

Comment: By what principle? Can you please elaborate on that?

Comment: A closer "same principle" word might be, say, [plummeted](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/plummet). There's no "right/wrong" for many such words (cf. [travelled, focused](http://www.future-perfect.co.uk/grammartips/grammar-tip-travelled-traveled.asp)), but the general trend (esp. in the US) is to discard the doubled consonant if it doesn't seriously impact on legibility.

Answer (score 0):

The rule we learned somewhere in school is that if the vowel is a short one, there should be a double consonant.  For example:  exhibitting, promoting, biting, rotting.

Comment: It depends on whether the final syllable of that short vowel is stressed. It so, then double it as in *admitting, permitting, outwitting, committing*. However, **if not stressed at the end, do not double it** — as in *auditing, inhabiting, exhibiting, profiting, limiting, compositing, editing*.

Comment: Yes this is obviously the rule that led to my confusion too. I was not fully to the exception to it, some words look normal with it, some looks strange, and some keep switching how the look while I think about them (-:

Comment: @tchrist: It sounds like you might have an answer worth submitting. It would be best with some references to back it up.